# web service show localhost not IP in SOAP

Tags: web-services, jboss, wildfly

[image]I created a web service named WildflyTest and a method called HelloWorld and deployed it to my wildfly 11 server,the server ip is 10.10.9.151.I tried to test using SoapUI, and I can open the wsdl address http://10.10.9.151:8086/WildflyTest/HelloWorld?wsdl. But when I tested it in SOAP Ui, when I created a new request, the address is http://localhost:8086/WildflyTest instead of 10.10.9.151.Can anyone give me some suggestion where to check the reason? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your bind address. By default, `public` interface is configured to listen on the loopback address of 127.0.0.1. So if you start WildFly as: `./bin/standalone.sh`

Then the WildFly default page can be accessed as http://127.0.0.1:8080. Usually, /etc/hosts provide a mapping of 127.0.0.1 to localhost, and so the same page is accessible at http://localhost:8080. 8080 is the HTTP port where all applications are accessed.

On a multihomed machine, you may like to start WildFly and bind `public` interface to a specific IP address. This can be easily done as:

```
./bin/standalone.sh -b=10.10.9.151 //your server ip
```

Now the applications can be accessed at http://10.10.9.151:8080.

Refer following links for more info:

[Bind WildFly to a different IP address](http://blog.arungupta.me/bind-wildfly-different-ip-address-multihomed/)

[How to configure JBoss to bind to a different IP ?](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/how-to-configure-jboss-to-bind-to-a-different-ip)

Comment: Thx for the answer. Look like your suggestion is modification at the server side configuration, is it possible to do it at  this specific project?

Comment: You can not modify this for project specific. Bind address is used to expose your interface with the specified address.

Comment: @kkluo This setting should be at the server level. why would you need it at a project level

Comment: OK. But I wonder if some web service has the correct IP display, is it still this reason. I'm adding service to the server, and other web services which already installed at the server looks fine with correct IP display.

Comment: Where are getting this ip displayed? Can you share a screenshot

Comment: I added a screenshot in my post. Thx for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193743/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-kk-luo).